# Pass parameter on Extjs 6

Tags: php, extjs, extjs6

I am new in Extjs 6 but I want to pass parameter to php when grid row is clicked. Here is my code and its is complaining on php that the parameter is undefined. Please assist...

```
xtype: 'grid',
store: {
            type: 'myComment',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoDestroy: true,
            extraParams:{
                            employee: record.get("employee")
                        }
                    },
            columns: [
                       ....
                     ]
```

Please help I've been working on this one for days

Answer (score 0):

extraParams belong to the proxy configuration from your store.

In your case you should do something like this:

```
{ 
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: {
        type: 'myComment',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoDestroy: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            extraParams:{
                employee: record.get("employee")
            }
        }

    },
    columns: [....]
}
```

Here are some more informationen on this:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-extraParams

---

Since you are using ExtJs 6, it is recommended to use the MVVM architecture.
If you do not already know, I would recommend following instructions from Sencha:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/application_architecture/application_architecture.html

In your case you can separate the definition of the store from the view. Furthermore it would then be possible to change simple parameters in the view or also in the store using binding.